# Importrange where Row row(NamedRange) = true

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, named-ranges

On the "Import" sheet, we want to import "Main" but only the columns that have a checkbox checked on named range "checks" which happens to be range 1:1. Here is the formula I tried.

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jdpF-4b76XkZ8jASNwQmdK9hnd_XEpaVA9U6bPkUsyE/edit#gid=2083288698", "Main!1:999")),   "where Row"&Row(checks)&" is true", 0))
```

I also want to skip rows that are completely blank. Only import rows that have a value on at least one of the columns.

Here is the [link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jdpF-4b76XkZ8jASNwQmdK9hnd_XEpaVA9U6bPkUsyE/edit#gid=0)

Here is a screenshot.

[image: Picture of Main]

[image: Picture of Sheet to Import Main to.]

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1jdpF-4b76XkZ8jASNwQmdK9hnd_XEpaVA9U6bPkUsyE", "Main!1:999"))), 
 "where Col1 = 'TRUE'", )), "offset 1", ))
```

[image]

---

### update 1:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1jdpF-4b76XkZ8jASNwQmdK9hnd_XEpaVA9U6bPkUsyE", "Main!1:999"))), 
 "where Col1 = 'TRUE'", )), "offset 1", ), " ", CHAR(13))),,9^9))),
 "where Col1 is not null", ), " "), CHAR(13), " "))
```

[image]

---

### update 2:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(IF(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1jdpF-4b76XkZ8jASNwQmdK9hnd_XEpaVA9U6bPkUsyE", "Main!1:999")="", "×", IMPORTRANGE(
 "1jdpF-4b76XkZ8jASNwQmdK9hnd_XEpaVA9U6bPkUsyE", "Main!1:999")))), 
 "where Col1 = 'TRUE'", )), "offset 1", ), " ", CHAR(13))),,9^9))),
 "where not Col1 contains '×'", ), " "), CHAR(13), " "))
```

[image]

Comment: This sort of works but it still imports blank rows when it shouldn't and it also doesn't consider the named range "checks". So if I insert a row at the top, the checkbox row is no longer in Col 1 which breaks the formula.

Comment: @WilliamToscano you can change `offset 1` to `where Col1 is not null offset 1` which will filter out the empty rows

Comment: I just updated the spreadsheet using your offset suggestion. Looks like were closer to the solution. Ideally, I would prefer if it not only ignored blank rows but instead ignored rows that are not full. So if there's a blank cell in a row, then skip the row entirely. If you can help me find this solution, I really appreciate your time and help!!

Comment: @WilliamToscano try updates

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. What do you mean by updates?

Comment: @WilliamToscano answer was updated